# How to get all entities owned/assigned to particular user?

Tags: rest

How to get all entities/records owned/assigned to particular user via REST API at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no single method to get objects owned by a user. Records must always be accessed by type. To perform an exhaustive extraction of a user's owned records, you would need to obtain the global describe results and iterate over all of the sObjects in the instance.

You would then need to run one query or Bulk API job for each sObject for which ownership is meaningful. Note however that some objects have special-case restrictions on how they can be queried, like `ContentDocument`, and others may or may not have an individual owner depending on how your instance is configured, like `Asset`.

It would be a much easier task if you had a set of specific sObjects you were interested in; if you truly want to extract *everything* a user owns, you'll have a number of special cases to deal with.